# Android runs on device but crashes on emulator

Tags: android, ant, robotium, android-testing

I'm setting up automatic testing for Android. 
If I run

> ant instrument install test

and have my physical device hooked up, it works like a charm:

> ```
> [echo] Running tests ...
>  [exec] 
>  [exec] com.abc.test.MainActivityUnitTest:.
>  [exec] Test results for InstrumentationTestRunner=.
>  [exec] Time: 3.362
>  [exec] 
>  [exec] OK (1 test)
>  [exec] 
>  [exec]
> ```

If I deploy this on an emulated device, I get the following:

> ```
> [echo] Running tests ...
>  [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
>  [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.abc.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner} from pid=1134, uid=1134 not allowed because package com.abc.test does not have a signature matching the target com.abc
>  [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
>  [exec] java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.abc.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner} from pid=1134, uid=1134 not allowed because package com.abc.test does not have a signature matching the target com.abc
>  [exec]     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
>  [exec]     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
>  [exec]     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startInstrumentation(ActivityManagerNative.java:3188)
>  [exec]     at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:864)
>  [exec]     at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:282)
>  [exec]     at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
>  [exec]     at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:76)
>  [exec]     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
>  [exec]     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:243)
>  [exec]     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

I am using ant to build and Robotium to test.
Does anybody have an idea?

EDIT:
I read that there could be some kind of problem with the signing of a previously installed version of the app. So I wiped the emulator and deployed again. This time I got:

> ```
> [echo] Running tests ...
>  [exec] 
>  [exec] com.abc.MainActivityUnitTest:INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=Native crash
>  [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=Native crash: Segmentation fault
>  [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
> ```

As anthonymasson suggested I checked my device configuration and the SD-Memory was set to 0.
Now I got the following:

> ```
> [echo] Running tests ...
>  [exec] 
>  [exec] com.abc.test.MainActivityUnitTest:INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=Process crashed.
>  [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
> ```

If I run the test in ADT it is actually green. But in the logcat there is following exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Any idea what that means? Google isn't very helpful...

Comment: Is your emulator running the same version as your device?  Also, have you updated the emulator software from the SDK Manager?

Comment: Yes, they are both running 4.4.2. Also my Android SDK Manager shows that everything's up to date.

Comment: are you using something like Bluetooth? Cause the emulator is not able to emulate Bluetooth.

Comment: No, I'm not using bluetooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost my complete journey is described in the answer by now.

But the final nail in my coffin is following:
The tests are green, because they run before the error occurs.
The error is related to my app trying to read hardware information that is not available on the emulator.

Someone suggested to try out [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/).
I've not yet looked into that, but if someone has the same issue as this, he might have luck with that.

I'll update this as soon as I have more input.

Answer (score 1):

Check your RAM/SD devide.
Normaly is the configuration of your VM.
Your program try to access to something doesn't exist.

Comment: That helped, but still didn't make this thing run.

Comment: Ok ! Now it's because you have a wrong signature of your apk ! You try to export ? If you try to install this manualy I have find this method : 
1) Un-zip the apk file 
2) del META-¬INF (folder) 
3) Do a new zip -> apk file like : test.apk.zip 
4) rename to test.apk 
5) -> try again : ant instrument install test 
6) Confirm if work

Comment: Thanks, but as I stated in my (edited) question: After I followed your advice the tests ran green (so it deployed correctly), but there was yet another error, which I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.graphmasters.nunav.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner} from pid=1134, uid=1134 not allowed because package com.graphmasters.nunav.test does not have a signature matching the target com.graphmasters.nunav
 [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
 [exec] java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.graphmasters.nunav.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner} from pid=1134, uid=1134 not allowed because package com.graphmasters.nunav.test does not have a signature matching the target com.graphmasters.nunav
```

check **com.abc** and **com.abc.test** both signatures

Comment: Although you are absolutely correct, this was not my case.